# Update only the time from a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

How can I update and change only the time-section of a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in postgres SQL?

I have to INSERT INTO a TABLE a new VALUE with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to get the correct year, month and day. The Time needs always to be 10 PM.

I tried to find a function where I eventually just get a TIMESTAMP with the current Year,month, day and the default time of 00:00:00. Later I tried to DATEADD 22:00:00 Into it. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: if it is always 10pm can you just not write it to db?

Comment: `select current_date + '22:00'::time;`. There is no `DATEADD` in Postgres, that is a SQL Server function. You need to spend time here [Date/Time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: The date is always the current one and the time needs to be for my specific insertion 10PM.  The VALUES (current_date + '22:00:00'::time) worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time part is the same for **all** rows without exception, I would not store it at all. Use a `date` column then turn that into a timestamp when selecting from the table:

```
select the_column + time '22:00:00' as the_column_adjusted
from the_table
```

Another alternative is to define a default value with a fixed time:

```
the_column timestamp default current_date + time '22:00:00'
```

This approach can also be used during an INSERT:

```
insert into the_table (the_column)
values (current_date + time '22:00:00');
```

To change existing rows, you can convert the timestamp to a date, then add the desired time back:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = the_column::date + time '22:00:00'
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert current_timestamp, which is of type "timestamptz" (short for "timestamp with time zone"), to a "date", then back to "timestamp with time zone", which will make it 00:00 at current timezone used by connection, and then add 22h:

```
=> select current_timestamp::date::timestamptz+'22h'::interval;
 2022-11-05 22:00:00+01
```

You can simplify this with just using current_date:

```
=> select current_date::timestamptz+'22h'::interval;
 2022-11-05 22:00:00+01
```

If you want to make it independent from current connection timezone, and just use UTC date (or any other time zone you need), you can use:

```
=> select ((current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC')::date::timestamp+'22h'::interval)::timestamptz;
 2022-11-05 22:00:00+01
```

But, if hour is not important, then "date" type would be better and more efficient to store than "timestamp with time zone".

[And never ever use "timestamp" type (short for "timestamp without timezone") for anything.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29)